# redmine upgrade to 3.4.4 not working [ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `default_users_time_zone')]

Tags: docker, upgrade, redmine

Every thing worked fine for me with Redmine 3.3. Now I wanted to upgrade to 3.4.4 and Redmine is no longer running. I searched the internet but did not find the exact same problem. Similar problems where caused by plugins but I do not have any plugins installed. I use the Passenger Docker image of Redmine.

The logs give me the following error message:

```
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Current user: anonymous
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0/login?back_url=http%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%2F
Filter chain halted as :check_if_login_required rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 60ms (ActiveRecord: 3.7ms)
App 179 stdout: 
Started GET "/login?back_url=https%3A%2F%2Fredmine.mydomain.tld%2F" for 95.90.204.176 at 2018-03-14 19:10:26 +0000
Processing by AccountController#login as HTML
  Parameters: {"back_url"=>"https://redmine.mydomain.tld/"}
  Current user: anonymous
  Rendered account/login.html.erb within layouts/base (24.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 219ms (ActiveRecord: 4.3ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `default_users_time_zone' for #<Class:0x00000000055f2120>
Did you mean?  default_users_hide_mail):
    11: <%= favicon %>
    12: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.0', 'application', 'responsive', :media => 'all' %>
    13: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'rtl', :media => 'all' if l(:direction) == 'rtl' %>
    14: <%= javascript_heads %>
    15: <%= heads_for_theme %>
    16: <%= call_hook :view_layouts_base_html_head %>
    17: <!-- page specific tags -->
  app/models/user_preference.rb:44:in `initialize'
  app/models/user.rb:949:in `pref'
  app/helpers/application_helper.rb:1451:in `javascript_heads'
  app/views/layouts/base.html.erb:14:in `_app_views_layouts_base_html_erb__2446195152155203147_36658300'
  lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:in `sudo_mode'
```

What could that be? I need to upgrade to 3.4 because I want to use a plugin but the plugin requires version 3.4 in use.

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault! I did not copy every new settings file to my mounted config directory.